# Django filter __date with timezone aware

Tags: django, datetime, timezone

Assume

1. I am using Django 2.x and use default settings. i.e, `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'` and `USE_TZ = True`
2. I am recording data in Honolulu, Hawaii, which means 2019-4-9 9pm (user time) in Honolulu is 2019-4-10 in UTC (server time)

Now I want to filter by 2019-4-9 Honolulu time (user time)

Here is what a demo code

```py
class TimelineTable(models.Model):
    accessed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.accessed}'
```

Here is the data in TimelineTable (recorded in **2019-4-9 Honolulu time**)

```
ID      accessed       
1       2019-04-10 07:19:30.319881 
2       2019-04-10 07:19:35.004506
3       2019-04-10 07:19:37.612088
```

Without considering timezone, fetch data works fine

```py
>>> TimelineTable.objects.filter(accessed__date=datetime.date(2019, 4, 9))
<QuerySet []>
>>> TimelineTable.objects.filter(accessed__date=datetime.date(2019, 4, 10))
<QuerySet [<TimelineTable: 2019-04-10 07:19:30.319881+00:00>, <TimelineTable: 2019-04-10 07:19:35.004506+00:00>, <TimelineTable: 2019-04-10 07:19:37.612088+00:00>]>
```

## Now the problem is with timezone.

## I am talking to server: Hey, give me those entries I recorded in 2019-4-9 at Honolulu.

```py
>>> Honolulu = pytz.timezone("Pacific/Honolulu")
>>> t = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 9, tzinfo=Honolulu)
>>> TimelineTable.objects.filter(accessed__date=t)
<QuerySet []>
```

I expected 3 entries, but nothing happens.

How to get these entries, without any bugs?

Comment: What is the value of `USE_TZ` settings variable?

Comment: as mentioned above, all the settings are by default. i.e USE_TZ = True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
t = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 9, 14, 00, 00, tzinfo=Honolulu)
d = t.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
TimelineTable.objects.filter(accessed__date=d.date())
# OR 
TimelineTable.objects.filter(accessed__gte=t)
```

Following code will **not** work:

```
t = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 9, tzinfo=Honolulu)
d = t.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
TimelineTable.objects.filter(accessed__date=d.date())
```

#### Explanation

When you generate `datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 9)`, it will return time `datetime.time(0, 0)`. When you convert it to `UTC`, the date won't be changed because its not the time difference between UTC and Honolulu is not 24 hours.

Comment: I see. 2019-4-9 at Honolulu, morning and night, actually includes two days in UTC.  I think I should not use date