# Weird behavior in django __date filter

Tags: django, datetime

I'm trying to filter the model by date.

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

There are 4 entries that were created at `date(2020, 3, 28)`:

```
2020-03-28 06:28:14.475307+00:00
2020-03-28 06:16:05.312023+00:00
2020-03-28 06:11:27.322146+00:00
2020-03-28 06:03:27.500164+00:00
```

When I'm doing this:

`Participant.objects.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.date(2020, 3, 28), created_at__lt=datetime.date(2020, 3, 29))`

I'm getting these 4 entries.

But, when I'm doing this:

`Participant.objects.filter(created_at__date=datetime.date(2020, 3, 28))`

I'm getting an empty queryset.

I have:

```
TIME_ZONE = "UTC"
USE_TZ = True
```

I'm in timezone `Asia/Kolkata`
I'm using django version 2.2, Mysql, python version 3.6.7

I have seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55608903/5157204 but I'm unable to figure out what the problem is. Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Comment: Have you check what the timezone in your machine?

Comment: @SancaKembang I'm at UTC+5.30

Comment: Previously I have the same problem, the timezone in django make me confused. Then I found the best solution to handle that problem, it is _"handle the timezone in computer machine, not in your django app"_, for example in ubuntu: `sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kolkata` and then setup your `USE_TZ = False`. Whevener you use the datetime / django timezone it will directly refers to your timezone for your computer machine. hope it help.

Comment: @SancaKembang Thanks for the advice. I've seen in this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#troubleshooting that it is not recommended to convert datetime to date. So, I'll just take a different approach for filtering for now.