# Chaining django queries on dates not working as expected

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a Django 4.2 app (mysql  Ver 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))) with a model Album. The Album model has a `DateTimeField` called `date`.

I run a query to select albums by the year in launch_date:

```
>>> launch_date = datetime(2014, 5, 10)
>>> albums = Album.objects.filter(date__year=launch_date.year)
>>> albums
<QuerySet [<Album: 732 - September 30, 2014>, <Album: 734 - February 6, 2009>, <Album: 735 - March 29, 2010>, <Album: 736 - April 5, 2010>, <Album: 738 - May 20, 2014>]>
>>> for a in albums:
        print(a.album_id, a.date.year, a.date.month)
732 2014 10
734 2014 10
735 2014 10
736 2014 10
738 2014 5
```

Which is what I expected.

However, when I run this query to further filter the albums by month, it fails. I expected the query to return the one album with `album_id` = 738:

```
>>> albums.filter(date__month=launch_date.month)
<QuerySet []>
```

These chained filters do not produce the results I expected, either:

```
>>> Album.objects.filter(date__year=2014, date__month=5)
<QuerySet []>
>>> Album.objects.filter(date__year=launch_date.year).filter(date__month=launch_date.month)
<QuerySet []>
```

What am I doing wrong?

A short update. I ran these queries with these results, which do not make a lot of sense:

```
>>> Album.objects.filter(date__startswith='2014-05')
<QuerySet [<Album: 738 - May 20, 2014>]>
>>>> Album.objects.filter(date__contains='2014-05')
<QuerySet [<Album: 738 - May 20, 2014>]>
>>> Album.objects.filter(date__year=2014).filter(date__month=5)
<QuerySet []>
```

I enabled showing sql used in queries, and this is what I get.

```
query1 = Album.objects.filter(date__year=2014)
logger.debug("query1=%s" % query1)
query1=<QuerySet [<Album: 732 - September 30, 2014>, <Album: 738 - May 20, 2014>]>

This is the SQL generated for query 1:

SELECT `Album`.`album_id`, `Album`.`title`, `Album`.`description`, `Album`.`date`, `Album`.`cover_image_id`, `Album`.`sort_option`, `Album`.`sort_order`, `Album`.`created`, `Album`.`updated`, `Album`.`is_published` FROM `Album` WHERE `Album`.`date` BETWEEN '2014-01-01 07:00:00' AND '2015-01-01 06:59:59.999999' ORDER BY `Album`.`album_id` ASC LIMIT 21; args=('2014-01-01 07:00:00', '2015-01-01 06:59:59.999999')


query2 = Album.objects.filter(date__year=launch_date.year).filter(date__month=5)
logger.debug("query2=%s" % query2)
query2=<QuerySet []>

The SQL for query2:
    
SELECT `Album`.`album_id`, `Album`.`title`, `Album`.`description`, `Album`.`date`, `Album`.`cover_image_id`, `Album`.`sort_option`, `Album`.`sort_order`, `Album`.`created`, `Album`.`updated`, `Album`.`is_published` FROM `Album` WHERE (`Album`.`date` BETWEEN '2014-01-01 07:00:00' AND '2015-01-01 06:59:59.999999' AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CONVERT_TZ(`Album`.`date`, 'UTC', 'America/Phoenix')) = 5) ORDER BY `Album`.`album_id` ASC LIMIT 21; args=('2014-01-01 07:00:00', '2015-01-01 06:59:59.999999', 5)
```

In case it helps, here is the `Album` model:

```
class ViewsMixin(models.Model):
    views = GenericRelation('viewcount.Views')
    recent_views = GenericRelation('viewcount.RecentViews')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

def get_default_date():
    #return datetime(1970, 1, 1)
    return datetime.now()

class PublishedAlbumsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_published=True)
 
class Album(ViewsMixin):
    def get_default_cover_image():
        default_image_id = Image.objects.get(image_id=ImageTags.objects.get(tag_id_id=Tags.objects.get(tag_name="Default Image")).image_id_id).image_id
        return default_image_id    
    
    album_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=get_default_date)   
    cover_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=get_default_cover_image)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True)
    sort_option = models.CharField(choices=settings.ALBUM_SORT_OPTIONS, default='creation_date', max_length=16)
    sort_order = models.CharField(choices=settings.ALBUM_SORT_ORDER, default='ascending', max_length=16)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name="date created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, verbose_name="last update")
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedAlbumsManager()
    
    def __str__(self):
        #return self.title
        return "%s - %s" % (self.album_id, self.title)
```

Regarding timezone issues, I checked mysql server and my Ubuntu 22.04 system. This is what I found.

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+

mark@piranha:~$ ls -alh /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jan 25 14:41 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Phoenix
```

Phoenix is GMT-7 with no DST.

Comment: Add query generated by ORM to the question and tag your DBMS.

Comment: Done. The DB is MySQL and the generated sql is right above the Album model. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Try filtering by `date__day=5`. My quess is django and db are treating dates in different format/timezone. I don't have much experience with MySql but `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CONVERT_TZ(`Album`.`date`, 'UTC', 'America/Phoenix')) = 5` - here is american timezone and one of american date formats is `MM-DD-YYYY` where date and month switch places. When Django generates `'2014-01-01', '2015-01-01` - these dates are the same in both `MM-DD` and `DD-MM` but when it tries to use DBMS-side conversions there is a chance that actually day is 5 not month stored on DB side (just a guess).

Comment: And/or it's just a timezone issue and the actual date is 1st of may or 31st of may and with adjusting to american timezone date switches to the nearest day of 4th or 6th month. Looks like the lag between DB timezone and UTC is 7 hours (see datetimes in generated query) it is a lot. Try setting `USE_TZ=false` in your settings.py and read manual for MySql to set correct timezone or make your DB TZ-independent.

Comment: Take a look at this [django docs page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) and [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607796/django-filter-date-with-timezone-aware)

Comment: Filtering by date__day did not work.
`Album.objects.filter(date__year=2014).filter(date__day=5)

<QuerySet []>`

Comment: I also thought it might be a timezone issue, so I tried filtering on a  month range, but that did not work.
`Album.objects.filter(date__year=2014).filter(date__month__gte=4).filter(date__month__lte=6)
<QuerySet []>`

Comment: There is no change in the query results when I set `USE_TZ=False`. It was originally set to `USE_TZ=True`.